# Make Runge Kutta Faster

Tags: python, numerical-methods

Trying to speed up calculation of Lagrangian trajectories given a 2D fluid field.

So far, using 4th order RK, have:

```
    for n in range(tau):

        t=2*n
        [x1,z1]=[x+0.5*U_xz[t](x0,z0),z+0.5*W_xz[t](x0,z0)]

        t+=1
        [x2,z2]=[x+0.5*U_xz[t](x1,z1),z+0.5*W_xz[t](x1,z1)]
        [x3,z3]=[x+U_xz[t](x2,z2),z+W_xz[t](x2,z2)]

        t+=1
        [x4,z4]=[x+U_xz[t](x3,z3),z+W_xz[t](x3,z3)]
        [x0,z0]=[(x1+2*x2+2*x3+x4)/6.0,(z1+2*z2+2*z3+z4)/6.0]

        x=x%nx
```

Last few lines not so important.
U_xz and W_xz are functions (linearly interpolated from data at discrete timesteps).

Would like to speed things up a bit, any suggestions, @jit maybe?

Comment: Using `numpy.ndarray` instead of Python-`lists` would certainly help a lot if there is a lot of numeric computation on `lists`. Also `Cython` might help (defining numbers as type `int` or `double`). Are `x`, `y` and `z` just scalar values (numbers) or lists? Please let us have a look at your other functions, as they seem to do the computational work.

Comment: Thanks for reply! U_xz and W_xz are stacks of interp2d functions. 
`U_xz=[]` and `W_xz=[]`  become stacks of `U_xz.append(scipy.interpolate.interp2d(X,Z,U_out[:,:,i],kind='linear'))` and
`W_xz.append(scipy.interpolate.interp2d(X,Z,W_out[:,:,i],kind='linear'))` respectively. Interpolation routines are only called once at the start whereas I have to do this integration around 100,000 times while `tau` < 1,000 typically. The variables `x` and `z` are floats which I need to recalculate for every `tau`. Can try to use `np.array` sure, did wonder if that would make a difference.